# ¿Es posible usar tipos como parámetros en Java?

Tags: java

Tengo dos clases `X` e `Y` con los mismos miembros estáticos:

```
class B {
    public static final String Base = "Base";
}

class X extends B {
    public static final String Primero = "Primera A";
    public static final String Segundo = "Segunda A";
}

class Y extends B {
    public static final String Primero = "Primera B";
    public static final String Segundo = "Segunda B";
}
```

En otra clase, necesito una función que use una u otra clase según unas condiciones:

```
class C {
    public <Datos> void f() {
        System.out.println("Operación " + Datos.Base);
        System.out.println("Operando " + Datos.Primero);
        System.out.println("Operando " + Datos.Segundo);
    }
}
```

La idea es usar `C` de esta forma:

```
C c = new C();
c.f<X>();
c.f<Y>();
```

Pero el código mostrado como ejemplo no compila, ¿es posible conseguir algo así en Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 puntos:

- Los *generics* de Java solo sirven para hacer comprobaciones **en tiempo de compilación**. Por razones de retrocompatibilidad, en tiempo de ejecución no hay diferencia entre

  ```
  C.<X>f();
  ```

  y

  ```
  C.<Y>f();
  ```

  Esto se denomina *type erasure*.
- Lo que buscas es la funcionalidad de *java reflection* (package `java.lang.reflect`), que permite "metaprogramar" accediendo a las clases, sus métodos y atributos de forma programática. Por ejemplo

  ```
  public void f(Class<? extends Datos> clazz) {
    Field campoPrimero = clazz.getField("Primero"); // [sic]
    System.out.println("campoPrimero " + field.get(null)); // Como es static, no tenemos que indicar de qué instancia obtenemos el campo.
  }
  ```

  invocado como

  ```
  C.f(X.class);
  ```

En general, aconsejo precaución con el uso de *reflection* porque es muy fácil entusiasmarse y hacer cosas que en principio parecen buenas ideas pero luego acaban por ser demasiado complicadas; en tu caso podría ser más apropiado definir el método `f()` en `B`

```
class B {
    public static final String Base = "Base";

    public void f() {
      System.out.println("Operación " + Datos.Base);
      System.out.println("Operando " + this.getPrimero());
      System.out.println("Operando " + this.getSegundo());
    }

    protected abstract Object getPrimero();

    protected abstract Object getPrimero();
 }

class X extends B {
    public static final String PRIMERO = "Primera A";
    public static final String SEGUNDO = "Segunda A";

    protected Object getPrimero() {
      return X.PRIMERO;
    }

    protected Object getSegundo() {
      return X.SEGUNDO;
    }
}
```

o como mínimo definir `getPrimero()` y `getSegundo()` como métodos `public` de X.

Answer (score 1):

Al definir la clase C de la forma:

```
class C {
    public <Datos> void f() {
        System.out.println("Operación " + Datos.Base);
        System.out.println("Operando " + Datos.Primero);
        System.out.println("Operando " + Datos.Segundo);
    }
}
```

Estás diciendo que "Datos" es un tipo genérico, pero no especificas ninguna restricción para el. Por lo que no es posible inferir que tenga los miembros Base, Primero ni Segundo.

En su lugar, `<Datos>` tendría que ser `<Datos extends X>` o `<Datos extends Y>`, pero careceria de utilidad, ya que solo funcionaría para parametros X o Y respectivamente.

Los tipos si pueden ser parámetros pero no de la forma en que los quieres utilizar. Por ejemplo, para crear listas con tipo específico podrías usar:

```
void asd() {
    List<String> strings = newList(); //equivalente a this.<String>newList()
    List<Number> numbers = newList();

    strings.add("asd");
    numbers.add(12);

    System.out.println(strings);
    System.out.println(numbers);
}

public <T> List<T> newList() {
    return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Donde el tipo específico se infiere del contexto, o se especifica anteponiendo el tipo al método.